# Django Url direct error

Tags: django, django-urls

My Django urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^login', views.login_page, name='login'),
url(r'^logout', views.logout_page, name='logout'),
url(r'^register', views.register_page, name='register'),
url(r'^create_book', views.create_book, name='create_book'),

url(r'^^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.book_details, name='book_details'),

url(r'^^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/create_entry$', views.create_entry, name='create_entry'),   ]
```

I am trying to do this:

```
{% url 'book:book_details' book.pk %}
```

It gives this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
```

`Reverse for 'book_details' with keyword arguments '{'book_id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/$']`

But going to `localhost:8000/ <some id>` directly in the browser works

How do I write the {% url %} part so that it goes to /(some id)

Comment: 1. It is client site ~> Open browser, press F12, Check the Console. (you will see the url request) Is it localhost:8000/id

Comment: No. it is lust localhost/             How do I fix that?

Comment: Remove the extra `^` from the url regex.. I think that's causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

change this line in template

```
{% url 'book:book_details' book.pk %}
```

to

```
{% url 'book_details' book.pk %}
```

and remove the extra `caret sign ^` from the url

```
url(r'^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.book_details, name='book_details'),

url(r'^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/create_entry$', views.create_entry, name='create_entry'),
```